# Adding Column on Publisher

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a new column on published database, does it gets automatically replicated on Subscriber.?

Using Transactional Replication on Sql Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.

Comment: Can you provide more informations ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Replicate schema changes enabled it will. Right click on the publication, subscription options, Replicate schema changes.

Comment: Thank you... Yes Schema changes are enabled